# How does package order affect resolving of dependencies in yum/dnf?

Tags: fedora, yum, dependencies, dnf

Background / xy-problem: I have some tool that needs `libcurl-devel`, but won't compile if there is a 32-bit version of `libcurl` present. Fixing that tool is for another day. Today I want to prevent installing a 32-bit version of `libcurl`. Or more precise: I'd like to learn how to anticipate and prevent similar problems in the future.

The 64-bit version of `libcurl` is pre-installed on a fresh fedora 38 docker container:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Fedora release 38 (Thirty Eight)
# dnf list --installed | grep libcurl
libcurl.x86_64                           8.0.1-3.fc38               @koji-override-0
```

However, for completeness, my installation script installs both `libcurl` and `libcurl-devel`. But this will install the 32-bit version of `libcurl`:

```
# dnf install libcurl libcurl-devel | grep curl
Package libcurl-8.0.1-3.fc38.x86_64 is already installed.
 libcurl-devel            i686         8.0.1-4.fc38         updates       987 k
 libcurl                  i686         8.0.1-4.fc38         updates       335 k
```

Unless I reverse the order of the packages:

```
# dnf install libcurl-devel libcurl | grep curl
 libcurl-devel            x86_64       8.0.1-4.fc38         updates       987 k
 libcurl                  x86_64       8.0.1-4.fc38         updates       313 k
```

I find this behaviour strange; I expected that the order of the packages would not matter.

How does the package order affect the resolving of the dependencies in dnf/yum, and is it possible to predict what the effect of a specific ordering is?

---

Some clarification.

I suppose one cause of the problem is that the `libcurl` version of the currently latest fedora image is slightly outdated, `7.85.0-10.fc37` vs `7.85.0-11.fc37`. So it might be necessary to use exactly this version of fedora 37, which is https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/fedora/37/images/sha256-210908a224d08874dc70ca2013439c4e2849047c5bb8711802f86ee48b1cf3f5

A more complete example:

```
> docker run -ti fedora:37@sha256:210908a224d08874dc70ca2013439c4e2849047c5bb8711802f86ee48b1cf3f5

# dnf list --installed | grep curl
curl.x86_64                              7.85.0-10.fc37             @koji-override-0
libcurl.x86_64                           7.85.0-10.fc37             @koji-override-0

# dnf list --installed | grep i686
```

So there are no i686 packages at all initially.

Installing in the order `libcurl-devel libcurl` would work fine (using `--assumeno`):

```
# dnf install --assumeno libcurl-devel libcurl
Last metadata expiration check: 0:01:46 ago on Fri Oct  6 12:43:11 2023.
Package libcurl-7.85.0-10.fc37.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
===============================================================================================
 Package                     Architecture    Version                    Repository        Size
===============================================================================================
Installing:
 libcurl-devel               x86_64          7.85.0-11.fc37             updates          977 k
Upgrading:
 libcurl                     x86_64          7.85.0-11.fc37             updates          303 k
Installing dependencies:
 libpkgconf                  x86_64          1.8.0-3.fc37               fedora            36 k
 pkgconf                     x86_64          1.8.0-3.fc37               fedora            41 k
 pkgconf-m4                  noarch          1.8.0-3.fc37               fedora            14 k
 pkgconf-pkg-config          x86_64          1.8.0-3.fc37               fedora            10 k

Transaction Summary
===============================================================================================
Install  5 Packages
Upgrade  1 Package

Total download size: 1.3 M
Operation aborted.
```

Installing in the other order, `libcurl libcurl-devel`, would install i686 packages:

```
# dnf install --assumeno libcurl libcurl-devel
Last metadata expiration check: 0:01:23 ago on Fri Oct  6 12:43:11 2023.
Package libcurl-7.85.0-10.fc37.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
===============================================================================================
 Package                        Architecture   Version                   Repository       Size
===============================================================================================
Installing:
 libcurl-devel                  i686           7.85.0-11.fc37            updates         976 k
Upgrading:
 glibc                          x86_64         2.36-14.fc37              updates         2.2 M
 glibc-common                   x86_64         2.36-14.fc37              updates         359 k
 glibc-minimal-langpack         x86_64         2.36-14.fc37              updates          79 k
Installing dependencies:
 cyrus-sasl-lib                 i686           2.1.28-8.fc37             fedora          861 k
 gdbm-libs                      i686           1:1.23-2.fc37             fedora           60 k
 glibc                          i686           2.36-14.fc37              updates         2.0 M
 glibc-gconv-extra              x86_64         2.36-14.fc37              updates         1.7 M
 keyutils-libs                  i686           1.6.1-5.fc37              fedora           32 k
 krb5-libs                      i686           1.19.2-13.fc37            updates         770 k
 libbrotli                      i686           1.0.9-9.fc37              fedora          317 k
 libcom_err                     i686           1.46.5-3.fc37             fedora           26 k
 libcurl                        i686           7.85.0-11.fc37            updates         329 k
 libevent                       i686           2.1.12-7.fc37             fedora          279 k
 libgcc                         i686           12.3.1-1.fc37             updates         123 k
 libidn2                        i686           2.3.4-1.fc37              updates         161 k
 libnghttp2                     i686           1.51.0-1.fc37             updates          80 k
 libpkgconf                     x86_64         1.8.0-3.fc37              fedora           36 k
 libpsl                         i686           0.21.1-6.fc37             fedora           64 k
 libselinux                     i686           3.5-1.fc37                updates          91 k
 libsepol                       i686           3.5-1.fc37                updates         336 k
 libssh                         i686           0.10.5-1.fc37             updates         224 k
 libunistring                   i686           1.0-2.fc37                fedora          551 k
 libverto                       i686           0.3.2-4.fc37              fedora           21 k
 libxcrypt                      i686           4.4.36-1.fc37             updates         123 k
 openldap                       i686           2.6.4-1.fc37              updates         273 k
 openssl-libs                   i686           1:3.0.9-1.fc37            updates         2.1 M
 openssl-pkcs11                 x86_64         0.4.12-2.fc37             fedora           74 k
 pcre2                          i686           10.40-1.fc37.1            fedora          234 k
 pkgconf                        x86_64         1.8.0-3.fc37              fedora           41 k
 pkgconf-m4                     noarch         1.8.0-3.fc37              fedora           14 k
 pkgconf-pkg-config             x86_64         1.8.0-3.fc37              fedora           10 k
 zlib                           i686           1.2.12-5.fc37             fedora           92 k
Installing weak dependencies:
 glibc-gconv-extra              i686           2.36-14.fc37              updates         1.7 M
 openssl-pkcs11                 i686           0.4.12-2.fc37             fedora           76 k

Transaction Summary
===============================================================================================
Install  32 Packages
Upgrade   3 Packages

Total download size: 16 M
Operation aborted.
```

---

New findings: the problem might have something to do with `libcurl-minimal`.

Running the [fedora live disc image](https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/37/Workstation/x86_64/iso/Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-37-1.7.iso), e.g. on QEMU, and running `dnf install libcurl libcurl-devel` also lets dnf install `libcurl.i686` ([screenshot 1](https://ibb.co/5BYkKK0)). However, there `dnf` explains that this is due to a conflict with the installed `libcurl-minimal.i686`, and gives a suggestion to add `--best --allowerasing` ([screenshot 2](https://ibb.co/prY7HnT)), which indeed lets it install `libcurl.i686`.

And low and behold, adding `--best --allowerasing` also works in the docker container, even though `libcurl-minimal` is not actually installed on that image. So my guess is that there is still a remnant somewhere of `libcurl-minimal.i686` that makes dnf think there is a problem where there is none.

Comment: DNF installs the default architecture packages unless instructed otherwise (there are ways to override this). If you never had the x86-64 package installed, and only had the i686 version installed, the development package will naturally be i686. AFAIK there's never been any special order handling.

Comment: That's the weird thing, `libcurl.i686` is not installed at the start at all, only `libcurl.x86_64`, but a slightly outdated version. Both the 32 bit and 64 bit versions of `libcurl` are installed after doing `dnf install libcurl libcurl-devel`, but only the 64-bit version of `libcurl-devel`.

Comment: `Both the 32 bit and 64 bit versions of libcurl are installed after doing dnf install libcurl` this mustn't be happening. There's something funky with your image.

Comment: The 64-bit is already installed in the image. The 32-bit version is only installed when doing `dnf install libcurl libcurl-devel`; so when installing both `libcurl` and the development package at the same time, and specifying them in that order.The 32-bit version is not installed in the other order, or when installing the packages in two separate dnf invocations (in any order).

Comment: I have a bog standard Fedora installation on multiple PCs and I cannot reproduce anything that you're describing: https://pastebin.com/mE5RKDH7 Again, you've got something weird going on, only I've no idea what.

Comment: In your example, you already have both packages installed and up-to-date; then dnf will indeed do nothing. libcurl should probably be outdated for the problem to occur. I'm using the "Official Docker builds of Fedora" maintained by "Fedora Release Engineering", so also 'bog standard' I suppose. I've clarified the mechanism to reproduce it.

Comment: This is **not** the case. I've just downgraded curl  libcurl and libcurl-devel and dnf does **not** attempt to install an i686 package: https://pastebin.com/bpGn4nE5

Comment: Oh, I noticed that I used fedora 38 in the first example, and fedora 37 in the second. But well, that at least shows that the issue occurs in different fedora distros.

Comment: I can fire up Fedora 37 and prove that what you're describing is not the case. I've been using RedHat distros for over 25 years, maybe I know a thing or two about them.

Comment: Thanks for the datapoint Artem. Perhaps it would also be a requirement that libcurl-devel should not be installed at all for this weirdness to happen. I'd be happy if you proof it wrong Artem. I don't know anything about fedora, that's why I'm here. Perhaps you could try to follow the instructions in the (updated) post? There are plenty of cases where the problem does not occur; I created those examples because for me they are reproducible.

Comment: Stock Fedora 37: https://i.ibb.co/zPB02VR/Fedora37.png Nothing that you're describing. With no libcurl-devel installed: https://i.ibb.co/fpYh88N/Fedora37-2.png I'm using `Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-37-1.7.iso`, i.e. 100% stock Fedora. Your image is changed in ways I cannot fathom. `dnf` under no circumstances installs non-default architecture packages unless you instruct it to do so, or dependent non-default arch packages are already installed. I cannot reproduce what you're describing.

Comment: Download the stock image yourself and check please. A VM needs at least 4GB of RAM. https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/37/Workstation/x86_64/iso/Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-37-1.7.iso

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and the memory limit Artem. I downloaded the iso in your link and ran it with qemu. Result, it still tries to install `libcurl.i686`: https://ibb.co/5BYkKK0 Note that you used different commands than I did; you forgot the `lib` part. To reproduce, use `dnf install libcurl libcurl-devel`. I'm not making any of this up.

Comment: On the live-cd there is an explanation though. Part of the output was cut-off too highlight the problem. https://ibb.co/prY7HnT shows the end of the output (top of the image). There dnf complains that it cannot install `libcurl.x86_64` due to a conflict with the installed `libcurl-minimal.x86_64`, and it gives a working suggestion to use `--best --allowerasing` which works. And low and behold, that also works on the docker image!!! Even though `libcurl-minimal` is not in the docker image (anymore?). Almost there, I'll add these new findings to the question.